# Swift simple problem "Use of unresolved identifier"

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to Swift programming language, I have an error at a simple program, I am trying to connect my ios app at one HM-10 Bluetooth module.

I attached the image with my code and the error

[image: code and error]

Thank you very much, guys! I hope one day I will be the one which answers here.

Comment: Post the code and the error message as text.

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from declaring variables outside of a class or struct. Put them into the class, it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, I think I missed that point from the tutorial.
Have a great day!

Comment: @pntandrei - Next time, in addition to including the code as text, if you’re having troubles with a tutorial, please include a link to it in your question.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, one should avoid using globals. If you make it a property of some class, that avoids the problem.

FWIW, the problem isn’t, strictly speaking, the use of the global, but rather the particular variable name you chose. For example, change the name of that global variable, it compiles fine:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

var manager: CBCentralManager!

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            print("BLE powered on")
        } else {
            print("Something wrong with BLE")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler has problems resolving this global symbol, `centralManager`, in the presence of multiple protocol methods of the same name (e.g., [`centralManager(_:didConnect:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518969-centralmanager), [`centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518791-centralmanager), etc.). One would have expected the compiler to be able to disambiguate between the global and the protocol methods given the context, but it doesn't. (One can also manifest this problem by defining a global called `tableView` in view controller that conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`.)

Bottom line, the technical problem is the choice of global variable name. But the correct answer is that it shouldn’t be a global at all.

---

Once you have your immediate issues behind you, you might reconsider whether to put this Bluetooth code in the view controller at all. Sure, in simple demo apps, we will often take shortcuts like that, but as your app grows, the view controller is going to become unwieldy. Also, you’re eventually going to want to add Bluetooth features to other view controllers, and you’re going to duplicate code.

Instead, make your own manager class, abstracting the details of `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheral` away from the view controllers. You can then provide then provide your view controllers a nice simple interface for interacting with the manager.

For example, you might have something like:

```
class BluetoothManager: NSObject {
    var isAvailableHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    
    private var manager: CBCentralManager? = nil
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func start() {
        guard manager == nil else { return }
        
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
}

extension BluetoothManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        isAvailableHandler?(central.state == .poweredOn)
    }
}
```

And then you can do things like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let deviceManager = BluetoothManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        deviceManager.isAvailableHandler = { [weak self] isAvailable in
            print(isAvailable ? "Powered on" : "Not available")
        }
        
        deviceManager.start()
    }
}
```

Now, in this example, I'm only handling `centralManagerDidUpdateState`, but you'd add additional closures or your own protocol to handle whatever events you want to expose to your view controllers. But hopefully this illustrates the idea.